# angular : lost data after sort datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I have a little problem when I sort a datatable. I made ​​a query to my api , I get my data well , but when I sort the interface, the data disappear. An idea?

JS

```js
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://dev:5001/api/1/phones').
    success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.phones= data;
    });
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>IP_ADDRESS</th>
                <th>MAC_ADDRESS</th>
                <th>STATUS</th>
                <th>VERSION</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat='phone in phones'>
                <td> {{ phone.id }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.ip_address }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.mac_address }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.status }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.version }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#example').DataTable({
                        "bPaginate": true, 
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": true});
                    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Where  is your sorting code?

Comment: are you using angular datatable directive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An idea?

Yes. Both angular and jQuery dataTables wants to manipulate the DOM. Both is going to action as soon the document is loaded === `ng-repeat` is not finished at the time the code reach `$(document).ready(function() {`, in fact it is propably not even initiated. So if you insist on using pure jQuery dataTables without directives, you must push `$('#example').DataTable()` into a later *digest* where the `ng-repeat` processing is finished.

Simply use a `$timeout` instead of the useless `ready()` chain :

```
$timeout(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable({
     "bPaginate": true, 
     "bLengthChange": false,
     "bFilter": false,
     "bInfo": false,
     "bAutoWidth": true
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old but I got a solution to the problem using in the directive attribute **`datatable`** the value **`ng`** like this:

```
<table 
     datatable="ng" 
     class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" 
     dt-options="controller.options">
</table>
```

I hop that helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `OrderBy` filter if you are planning just table sort

```
<tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="phone in phones | orderBy:'id'">
                <td> {{ phone.id }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.ip_address }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.mac_address }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.status }} </td>
                <td> {{ phone.version }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```